# Is there another way to ui android ?

Tags: android, user-interface

I do not want to use the XML

Is there another way to Android programming ?

Can I Programming with html or css .

Comment: Use this http://www.google.com, first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to create a User Interface in Android.

1. The XML way.
2. Dynamically creating your UI controls in the the Java activity, or the native  Acctivity in C++.
3. You can add a webview and program in javascript css html.
4. You can create a SurfaceView and a Renderer and create your UI with OpenGL ES.
5. Xamarin, lets you develop in C# with .Net for Android.

Comment: Give me lessons, books

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out PhoneGap (http://phonegap.com/). It's useful for developing apps cross-platform!